# Five conics problem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves, intersection-theory

I have a small question about one short sentence appearing in page : $290$ of the following electronic textbook : https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf

- **The short sentence says** :

Given five general plane conics $ C_1 , \dots , C_5 $. How many smooth conics are tangent to all five ?

- **Question** :

What do we mean by saying that a smooth conic is tangent to five general plane conics $ C_1 , \dots , C_5 $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your confusion about when a conic is tangent to another? Once you know this, five or a million makes little difference for definition.

Comment: Yes, my confusion is about when a conic is tangent to another. Can you give me its definition ? Thank you.  :-)

Comment: If $p \in C$ is a smooth point then there is a unique tangent line, written $T_pC$. We say that $C, C'$ are tangent if there is a point $p \in C \cap C'$ with $T_pC = T_pC'$.

Comment: For smooth conics, any point on it has a unique tangent line. Two smooth conics are tangent to each other means, they have some point in common and the tangent lines for both at this point are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Mohan and Nicolas for your help.  :-)